Time Constant Equalizer
I found a device made decades ago and long forgotten now. It was a simple device that compensated for the non-linearities produced by a moving magnet cartridge for audio. I am not a scientist just an end user in music production. Apparently frequencies produce a “braking force” in the cartridge that produces errors of phase, particularly in high frequencies. Can anyone explain what a time constant equalization in simple terms

Do you mean mag. recording tape EQ bias?

Do you mean a "dynamic" pick-up for a turntable? If so, you may be asking about the RIAA equalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization

What you describe sounds like a standard 1970's photo cartridge preamp with RIAA equalization.  There are many websites devoted to the history, details, and design of this circuit.  Many have the details about the equalization curve time constants.
The "braking force" is the Lorentz force, caused by the the current induced into the cartridge coils by the moving magnets.  When is induced into a wire by a changing magnetic field, that current creates its own magnetic field that opposes the inducing one.  This means that with phono cartridges and dynamic microphones, the preamp input impedance appears as a load on the cartridge coils.  Just as with a power generator, the lower the load impedance, the harder it is to make things move.  Thus, the preamp input impedance affects the frequency response of the cartridge or microphone.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force

In all cases, the induced current mostly charges and discharges the cable and input capacitances. This produces nonlinear loading on the stylus. There is also a velocity-proportional loading akin to viscous loading that is due to the input resistance of the preamplifier, IIRC. All of those are frequency-dependent.

What was this ancient device called? A phonograph player with a moving magnet pickup.
That was simply a bass cut and treble boost on the recording with the exact opposite on phono playback. That way the track width could be kept small and the signal boosted the treble more above the surface noise.  A moving magnet attached to the diamond needle pickup was inserted inside a fixed electric coil cartridge was the most common design.
The sloped frequency response break points gives rise to the mathematical term “time constants” in microseconds per cycle, which is the inverse of cycles per second.
There was a controversy when the IEC wanted to add an extra constant to reduce wow and flutter effects from a record warp and motor hum.  It was never widely adopted after 1976 and eventually dropped in 2009 since this problem was mainly on low quality players.
History of RIAA in wiki.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization#:~:text=The%20time%20constants%20of%20the,from%20the%20corresponding%20RIAA%20values.
